# Spring data jpa pagination can edit count query?

Tags: pagination, spring-data-jpa

I have Big data my mysql in some table (10000000)

```
 Pageable setPage = PageRequest.of(form.getCurrentPage(),
                form.getListSizeInPage(),
                Sort.by("num").descending());
```

So. When i call the Query like this.

```
 Page<Entity> getList = repo.findall(setPage );
```

and mysql show findall query's call time is very short under 5sec.
But the page api has call

```
 select count(column) fomr table;
```

this query call time during 15sec over

could i change or edit count query?

Comment: Hi, very interesting, perhaps this answer might offer some useful info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976328/mysql-count-performance-on-very-big-tables   It might require a separate counter... Not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own method and annotated it with`@Query`.

This allows you to provide a custom `countQuery` or to return a `Slice` which doesn't use a count query at all.